# Getting A non-numeric value when combining strings PHP

Tags: php, string

I have this code:

```php
echo "<p>" + $username + "<\/p>"
```

and `$username` is a string. I get this error:
**Warning:** A non-numeric value encountered
I don't know why i get this. How can i fix this?

Comment: PHP uses a "." for string concatenation, not a "+" as many other languages. https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "." instead of "+" to concat strings, "+" is only for Arithmetics.